# Pandas source code _get_grouper calls itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I was looking at the following pandas [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1700680381bdbfbc1abe9774f96881801b24d6ca/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py#L111)：

```
def _get_grouper(self, obj, validate=True):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    obj : the subject object
    validate : boolean, default True
        if True, validate the grouper
    Returns
    -------
    a tuple of binner, grouper, obj (possibly sorted)
    """

    self._set_grouper(obj)
    self.grouper, exclusions, self.obj = _get_grouper(self.obj, [self.key],
                                                      axis=self.axis,
                                                      level=self.level,
                                                      sort=self.sort,
                                                      validate=validate)
    return self.binner, self.grouper, self.obj
```

It looks like _get_grouper calls itself recursively. Wouldn't this result in a endless loop?

I tried to search for the parent class, but it seems that the Grouper class only inherits object class, and there is no other _get_grouper function defined in the file.

This puzzles me a little bit.

Comment: If it is calling itself, it should have been `self._get_grouper`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that outside the class there is another `_get_grouper` function, which is precisely the one that is being called in this code snippet.

If it were the same `_get_grouper` within the class that was called, it should instead be `self._get_grouper` given that it is an attribute of the class.

Here's a simple example to illustrate this:

```
class Sample():  
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.p = p
        if self.p:
            print_()
        else:
            self.print_()
    def print_(self):
        print('This is a function within the Sample class')

def print_():
    print('This is a function outside the Sample class')
```

---

```
s = Sample(p=True)
# This is a function outside the Sample class

s = Sample(p=False)
# This is a function within the Sample class
```